# How to reset paper-dropdown-menu inside an iron-form?

Tags: javascript, polymer

Sample code:

```
<iron-form id="form1">
    <form method="get" action="/form/handler">
        <paper-input name="name" label="Name" required></paper-input>
        <paper-dropdown-menu label="Dinosaurs">
            <paper-listbox slot="dropdown-content" selected="1">
                <paper-item>allosaurus</paper-item>
                <paper-item>brontosaurus</paper-item>
                <paper-item>carcharodontosaurus</paper-item>
                <paper-item>diplodocus</paper-item>
            </paper-listbox>
        </paper-dropdown-menu>
        <paper-button raised on-click="_save">Save</paper-button>
        <paper-button raised on-click="_reset">Reset</paper-button>
      </form>
</iron-form>

...


_reset() {
    this.$.form1.reset();
}
```

When the 'Reset' button is clicked the dropdown is NOT set to its default value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with `paper-dropdown-menu` is that it has no mechanism to set a value on its own.

Rather than that it allows you to grab its contained `paper-listbox` via `contentElement` property and invoke a set method.

No magic that `iron-form` could perform here I'm afraid, so I'd extend the `_reset` method:

```
_reset() {
    this.$.myDropdown.contentElement.set('selected', null); // or whatever fallback
    this.$.form1.reset();
}
```

Of course you can refer to listbox directly too.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a variable for selected attribute:

```
 <paper-listbox slot="dropdown-content" selected="{{selected}}">
```

and define selected property at :

```
 static get properties() { return {
     selected: {type:Number, value:1},...
```

and set it 1 on reset function:

```
_reset() {
    this.set('selected', 1);  // 
    this.$.form1.reset();
}
```

It is Polymer way that you may use selected property when you submit form data.